# sympy subs() a list of values to evalue

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I have:

```
import sympy as sp

L1,L2,T = sp.symbols("L1,L2,T")

expr = L1 + L2*T
expr.subs([(L1,2),(L2,4),(T,[1,2,3,4])])
```

I want to evaluate T at every value in the list [2,5,7,8] but it doesn't evaluate the list.  Is there a way to do this so that each value in the list can get evaluated and get an output for each?  This is what I need:

```
 2+4*1 = 6
 2+4*2 = 10
 2+4*3 = 14
 2+4*4 = 18
```

Comment: Use good old fashion python iteration, one `subs` per number in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by hpaulj:

```
res = [expr.subs([(L1,2),(L2,4),(T, t)]) for t in [1,2,3,4]]
res
# out: [6, 10, 14, 18]
```

Comment: This works as expected.  Thanks.  What if L1 was another list of values.  I tried [expr.subs([(L1,x),(L2,4),(T, t)]) for t in [1,2,3,4] for x in [2,4,6]] which it does work but it duplicates the values

Comment: It doesn't duplicate the values: it evaluates `expr` for each value of `t` and for each value of `x`. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but if you want to evaluate `expr` for each pair of `t, x` then you would need to do: `[expr.subs([(L1,x),(L2,4),(T, t)]) for t, x in zip([1,2,3,4], [2,4,6])]` which outputs `[6, 12, 18]`. Note that the iteration over a zipped element is going to stop when the shortest list has been "traversed". In the above example, you see 3 outputs, corresponding to the `(t, x)` values of `(1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 6)`, respectively.